# Minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ of an irrational number $\alpha$ with $\alpha^3 + 3\alpha^2-2=0$

Tags: minimal-polynomials

I am revising for my exams and don't understand how to do the following question, any hints would be very helpful!

Find a minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is an irrational number satisfying $\alpha^3 + 3\alpha^2-2=0$.

I have the definition of a minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the rational numbers and what it means for $\alpha$ to be algebraic over the rational numbers.

Comment: Over the rational numbers you mean? Over $\mathbb{R}$ it would be not really nice to factor this expression...

Comment: Yes, sorry will edit my question

Comment: Either the cubic is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ or it is not. If it is, then it is the minimal polynomial. If it is not, then it factors as $(x - r) q(x)$ for some rational $r$, so that $q(\alpha) = 0$; since $\alpha$ is irrational, $q$ is irreducible.

Comment: Factorizing gives $(\alpha+1)(\alpha^2+2\alpha-2)$ so does this mean that since $\alpha$ is irrational the polynomial $\alpha^2+2\alpha-2$ is irreducible and so is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $X^3 + 3X^2 - 2$ factors as
$$X^3 + 3X^2 - 2 = (X + 1)(X^2 + 2X - 2).$$
The quadratic factor is irreducible (over ${\mathbb Q}$) because it has no roots (in ${\mathbb Q}$).

Since $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3 + 3X^2 - 2$, it is a root of either $X + 1$ or of $X^2 - 2X - 2$. Because $\alpha$ is irrational, it is not equal to $-1$, so it is a root of $X^2 + 2X - 2$.

So, $X^2 + 2X - 2$ is an irrediducible, monic polynomial with $\alpha$ as a root, so it is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.